# Can I scrape a website to identify headings and text under it?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to create a web scraper so that it identifies the headings and text related to it on the web page. Can anyone help in how can that be done?

[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0I2i.png)

For example, here in the image attached, "Prerequisites" is the heading and the text below is "corresponding text".

Comment: You mean headers?

Answer (score 1):

You should use python and `BeautifulSoup`, a library made for web scraping.

For a given url you extract the actual content of the page using `request` the following way :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

Once you have the object soup you can find all headings the following way :

```py
headings = list()

for i in range(1, 7):
    # <h1> to <h6>
    headings.extend(soup.findAll(f'h{i}'))
```

`headings` now contains all the headings from h1 to h6. Now to extract the text you just proceed as follows :

```
text_content = soup.text
```

Comment: But how do I get to know which text corresponds to which heading?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "corresponds to".

That question can make sense if you are talking about a <div> in which case you would need to find the children tag the following way : 

soup.find("div").findChild("p")

This will find the <p> element that are nested in the div.

But this is impossible for h1, h2, ..., h6 that are actually used the same way as p tags.

The question is hard to understand as it is. Can you specify what you mean by "corresponds to"?

Comment: I've edited the question and tried to explain the case properly. Please got through it once.